# Converges of integral, knowing the derivative has a limit

Tags: calculus, integration

$f: [0,\infty) \to \Bbb R$ we know that f>0 and f ' exists .$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (\ln f)'(x)=L<0$. Prove  that $\int _0^\infty f$ converges

Any hint would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $(\ln f)'(x) \le c < 0$ for all $x \ge x_0$, then 
$\ln f(x) \le \ln f(x_0) + \ldots $

Comment: So we can say that $f$ is monotone descending and positive, it's limit in infinity is zero, and then try using Cauchy Integral test for convergence to show the tail of the integral converges?

Comment: No, that's not enough.  You need an explicit bound.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the dots in your inequality stand for.

Comment: I know that $(\ln f)'(x) = \frac{f'}{f} \le c < 0$ . $f \ge 0 $ therefor $ f' <  0$ which mean $f$ is descending. Only that it's not enough information to know the area below $f$ goes to zero when x goes to infinity. 
$f$ can be for example a constant at the infinity, a therefore $\int _0 ^\infty f$  disconverges

Comment: Right, you have to use the $c$.  If you have a function $g$ and $g' \le c$ everywhere, what can you say about $g(x) - g(x_0)$?  Does "Mean Value Theorem" ring a bell?

Comment: I tried the Mean Value theorem with $f$ but it didn't lead to the solution.
Now that I tried again with $ln f$ I succeeded to bound the integral of $f$ with some integral of $e^{-c}$ which converges. 
thanks!